# session.setAttribute a textbox

Tags: jsp

Is there a way of assigning a session attribute to a textbox in jsp? i want to use a common textbox in all my app as referrence. else could you please suggest me a better way to approach.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question right: Do you want a textbox (HTML `<textarea>`) to appear on all JSPs? Do your want a common String attribute attached to all users' sessions - or both of these? Please be more specific about the desired behaviour and layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - `<input type="text" value="${sessionScope.yourkey}" />`